# Visual Studio 2017 y reportviewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer

A ver si explico correctamente el caso:

```
  1.- Intento realizar un report que visualiza los datos de un objeto.

  2.- Programo en Visual Studio 2017, c# y para escritorio (no asp .net).

  3.- Utilizo un report local (rdlc) y el componente report viewer para visualizarlo.
```

Si utilizo Visual Studio 2010, al insertar el report viewer en el formulario, se muestra el control y tiene un botón inteligente task manager en el cual puedo seleccionar el informe a mostrar y trabajar con las propiedades del mismo. Si ejecuto en Visual Studio 2010, me aparece correctamente el report.

Pasamos a Visual Studio 2017.... y para empezar el report viewer se muestra ahora como un componente, sin visualización alguna en el formulario. Al parecer la asociación con el report se realiza por programación, ya que no veo por ninguna parte la task manager; si lo ejecuto aquí, no obtengo absolutamente nada, sólo me aparece el formulario conternedor

El código que he puesto en el Form_Load contenedor del report vieweres el de abajo, en el que se especifica que el report es local, cual es, se añaden las dos listas de objetos de datos (Invoice y Detail) y se refresca el report viewer para que lo muestre. El resultado que obtengo es únicamente el formulario en blanco.

Alguna ayuda ?

Codigo

```
private void FrmReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    reportViewer2.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

    LocalReport localReport = reportViewer2.LocalReport;
    localReport.ReportPath = "ManagementReport.rdlc";
    localReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("GeneralDSManagementReport", Invoice));
    localReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DetailDSManagementReport", Detail));

    reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
}
```

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Es posible que no encuentre la ruta del informe? Intenta poner la ruta completa del archivo rdlc a ver

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema y llevo semanas buscando alguna solución en la web, pero no encuentro a casi nadie que comente esto; de hecho, eres el segundo al que veo que también le pasa. Pero tanto tú como el anterior, no obtuvieron respuesta de nadie.... Es muy frustrante, pues tengo mi aplicación parada a falta de poder imprimir el informe de datos.
A ver si alguien nos puede dar alguna idea....
Gracias de antemano a todos los que nos puedan ayudar.

Comment: Has intentado poner lo siguiente: `Me.reportViewer.RefreshReport()` Hace tiempo tuve un problema similar, era VS 2010 y ReportViewer 2010, lo interesante es que me pasaba lo mismo. El reporte comenzó a actualizarse correctamente al anteponer el `Me`. No me preguntes los detalles, hace tiempo que no programo en la plataforma .NET y estoy oxidado. Prueba eso y nos comentas. Saludos